# Combine multiple row values into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a result set that should be pulled into a report as one line. However, there can be multiple buyers associated to an order and these buyers are represented as a new row in the database. So for instance, I have the following...

```
SELECT
   O.OrdersID
   ,BS.LastName
FROM
   Orders O
LEFT JOIN 
   BuyerSeller BS ON O.OrdersID = BS.OrdersID
```

If there are multiple buyers, it will return the following result set as follows:

```
OrdersID | LastName 
----------------------
1        | Tester1
1        | Tester2 
1        | Tester3
```

I'd like it to return as the following (separated by columns):

```
OrdersID | LastName 
---------------------------------------
1        | Tester1, Tester2, Tester3
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: `sql` is not a platform, but a language.  Your answer is very dependent on the platform you are using.  Could you tag your post with the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ord.OrderID , substring
                         ((SELECT        ',' + BS.LastName AS [text()]
                             FROM    Orders O   LEFT JOIN BuyerSeller BS       ON O.OrderID = BS.OrderID
                             ORDER BY  O.OrderID FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 1000) LastName
```

FROM            Orders ord

This will return the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in `SSRS` you would need to

1. **Create a table** with `OrdersID` as Row group
2. Make sure there is **no detail section** inside the group. If there is one delete it without deleting the rows.
3. Write this **experession** for  `LastName`:

`=Join(Lookupset(Fields!OrdersID.Value, Fields!OrdersID.Value, Fields!LastName.Value, "myDataSet"), ", ")`

Remember SSRS is **case sensitive**.